# How to update user class in parse-platform using JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to update other user's information in Parse which is stored in User class. 
Initially I tried following code:

**1.**

```
var user = Parse.User;
var query = new Parse.Query(user);

query.equalTo("name", userName); //to find specific user

query.first({
     success: function(results) {
                //update that user's details
                results.set("name", newName);
                results.save();
      },
      error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
});
```

I got following error:

```
{code: 206, error: "Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError"}
```

**2.** Then I used Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(), as I figured out that we can not edit other user's details. But it didn't work either. And master key overrides all security, so it was not a good idea to use this code.

**3.** So I tried following code:

```
var user = Parse.User;
var query = new Parse.Query(user);

query.equalTo("objectId", userName);

query.first({
    success: function(results) {

                results.set("name", newName);

                results.save(null, { useMasterKey:true}).then(function(user) {console.log("updated!!!");}, function(error) {console.log(error); });

     },
     error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }
});
```

But I am getting '401 Unauthorized' error.

Does anyone know how to update other user's information in Parse? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `fetch` function after updated current user object. You can follow below sample:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
currentUser.set('name', 'New Name');
currentUser.save(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        currentUser.fetch();
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert('Failed to update object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
});
```